# How to add reference of vbproj(not .NET compiled) to a .NET vb project

Tags: .net, vb.net, dll, reference

I am working on a Transformation project, where I need to shift update the application to the latest version and from desktop-based to the server-based environment. The application **A** is build using vb .NET and there is a separate module **B** that is built using some other framework maybe but that is also a vb project.
[The vb project **B**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyoxe.jpg)
Now **A** is having some code which is using a class of **B** as following

`Dim Printer As New CustomPrinting.ChqPrint`
While adding a reference to DLL shows this error message:

[image: Error Message]

Comment: The image looks like pre-.NET (one of the VBA-based VBs, probably VB6).  Still, if it's a class library, I'd nonetheless expect you to be able to add a reference to it which would end up using COM interop to work with the classes and types.

Comment: @Craig I am not able to figure out how the previous developers were using these classes and DLLs. And now it is showing error for me. I just need suggestions on how to use this here.